# ocultar/mostrar n elementos "tr" a partir de otro elemento tr en una tabla

Tags: jquery, html

Actualmente sólo puedo mostrar/ocultar un solo elemento así:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Mostrar_Tabla").click(function () {
            if ($("#Tabla_Mostrar").is(":visible")) {
                document.getElementById("Tabla_Mostrar").style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("Tabla_Mostrar").style.display = '';
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <tr id="Mostrar_Tabla">
        <td>
            Dale Click Aqui
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Tabla_Mostrar">
        <td>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Pero necesito hacerlo funcionar con n elementos `tr`. ¿Cómo tendría que modificar mi script para que funcione con el html como éste?:

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr id="Mostrar_Tabla1">
        <td>
            Dale Click Aqui
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Tabla_Mostrar1">
        <td>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr id="Mostrar_Tabla2">
        <td>
            Dale Click Aqui
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Tabla_Mostrar2">
        <td>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Mostrar_Tabla3">
        <td>
            Dale Click Aqui
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Tabla_Mostrar3">
        <td>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cada `tr` al que le haces clic asígnale una clase (la misma para todos):

```
<table class="table">
    <tr id="Mostrar_Tabla1" class="Mostrar_Tabla">
        <td>
            Dale Click Aqui
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Tabla_Mostrar1">
        <td>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

En el código JavaScript, declara el evento `click` sobre los elementos con esa clase. En este evento, muestras u ocultas el `tr` cuyo id comience con `Tabla_Mostrar` que esté a continuación del `tr` en el que hiciste clic:

```
$('tr.Mostrar_Tabla').click(function(){
    $trOcultar = $(this).next('tr[id^="Tabla_Mostrar"]');

    if ($trOcultar.is(":visible")) {
        $trOcultar.css('display', 'none');
    }
    else {
        $trOcultar.css('display', '');
    }
});
```

Como alternativa, si no puedes o prefieres no agregar la clase a estos `tr`, puedes hacer que el evento afecte a los `tr` cuyo `id` comience con `Mostrar_Tabla`:

```
$('tr[id^="Mostrar_Tabla"]').click(function(){
    $trOcultar = $(this).next('tr[id^="Tabla_Mostrar"]');

    if ($trOcultar.is(":visible")) {
        $trOcultar.css('display', 'none');
    }
    else {
        $trOcultar.css('display', '');
    }
});
```

Comment: @Xique Mmm, cierto. Estaba mirando la tabla que está dentro del `tr` y me confundí; lo corrijo.

Answer (score 3):

Espero esto te sirva,

```js
function toggle(tableid){
  var id = jQuery(tableid).data('id')
  jQuery('#Tabla_Mostrar'+id).toggle();
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.opciones').on('click', function(){
    toggle(this)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <tr id="Mostrar_Tabla1" data-id="1" class="opciones">
        <td>
            Dale Click Aqui
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Tabla_Mostrar1">
        <td>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr id="Mostrar_Tabla2" data-id="2" class="opciones">
        <td>
            Dale Click Aqui
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Tabla_Mostrar2">
        <td>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr id="Mostrar_Tabla3" data-id="3" class="opciones">
        <td>
            Dale Click Aqui
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Tabla_Mostrar3">
        <td>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 3):

También me quedó de esta forma que es un poco más sencilla :

```js
$("tr.Galleta_Grande").click(function () { 
  $(this).next("tr.Galleta_Chica").toggle(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table> 
   <tr class="Galleta_Grande"> 
       <th>Click Aqui para mostrar/ocultar</th> 
   </tr> 
   <tr class="Galleta_Chica"> 
      <td > 
        XD 
      </td> 
    </tr>
   <tr class="Galleta_Grande"> 
       <th>Click Aqui para mostrar/ocultar</th> 
   </tr> 
   <tr class="Galleta_Chica"> 
      <td > 
        XD 
      </td> 
    </tr>
   <tr class="Galleta_Grande"> 
       <th>Click Aqui para mostrar/ocultar</th> 
   </tr> 
   <tr class="Galleta_Chica"> 
      <td > 
        XD 
      </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

he cambiado los `id` por `class` únicamente en el `tr` donde se le hará clic y he hecho uso de [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) de jQuery dejando el script de esta forma:

```
$('.Mostrar_Tabla').on('click',function(){
    if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) { 
        $(this).next().css('display', 'none');
    }
    else 
    {
        $(this).next().css('display', 'block');
    }
})
```

Lo que hace `$(this).next()` es seleccionar el siguiente hermano de `$('.Mostrar_Tabla')` el cual seria `<tr id="Tabla_Mostrar1">`

**Ejemplo:**

```js
$('.Mostrar_Tabla').on('click',function(){
 if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
  //console.log($(this).next())
  $(this).next().css('display', 'none');
 }
 else 
 {
  //console.log($(this).next())
  $(this).next().css('display', 'block');
 }
})

$('button').on('click',function(){
  //simulando append desde success ajax
  $('table.table:eq(0)').append('<tr>'+
        '<td>'+
            '<table class="table">'+
                '<tr>'+
                    '<td>1</td>'+
                    '<td>2</td>'+
                    '<td>3</td>'+
                    '<td>4</td>'+
                '</tr>'+
            '</table>'+
        '</td>'+
    '</tr>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Añadir +</button>
<table class="table">
    <tr class="Mostrar_Tabla">
        <td>
            Dale Click Aqui
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Mostrar_Tabla">
        <td>
            Dale Click Aqui
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr class="Mostrar_Tabla">
        <td>
            Dale Click Aqui
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Editare la respuesta haciendo un `append()` desde un botón que vendría siendo un `append()` desde ajax